# Getting ordered list to show number with Twitter Bootstrap + inputs

Tags: css

I made a js bin to show my issue: http://jsbin.com/zejanebedo/1/

It is probably something simple but I am banging my head against a wall here.

The numbers for the list items don't show up if the first child is an input.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

If you add `display: inline` to the input with the `form-control` class, then it fixes the problem.